# How to create has_many associated fields with the parent field in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was looking for a way to create comment along with the comment.

Below is schema table with schemas
1. posts table

# Table name: posts
    #
    #  id           :integer          not null, primary key
    #  post         :string(255)
    #  post_content :string(255)
    #  created_at   :datetime
    #  updated_at   :datetime
    #

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

2.comment table

# Table name: comments
    #
    #  id         :integer          not null, primary key
    #  comment    :string(255)
    #  post_id    :integer
    #  created_at :datetime
    #  updated_at :datetime
    #
    # Indexes
    #
    #  index_comments_on_post_id  (post_id)
    #

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Now, i want to create post with comment. How do i achieve it? plz, help.

Form partial

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :post %>
  <%= f.text_field :post_content %>
  <br>
  <span>put comments</span>  
  <%= f.fields_for :comments do |s|%>
    <%= s.text_field :comment %>
    <%= s.hidden_field :post_id ,value: @post.id%>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller code

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @post.comments.build
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.comments.build
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:post,:post_content,comment_attributes:[:comment])
    end
end
```

Comment: First step:In your `PostsController` in `new` method add this `@post = Post.new` and `@post.comments.build`.

Comment: @Pavan,can you point me to some tutorial or document regarding this ?

Comment: As, i am using i am using the same as you told. but it creates comment with nil

Comment: Post the `controller code` and `form code`.

Comment: @Pavan, i have put the necessary code part here.

Comment: Your `post_params` should be `params.require(:post).permit(:post,:post_content,comments_attributes:[:comment])` It is `comments_attributes` not `comment_attributes`

Comment: Thank you very much this has solved my problem. forgive me for this kind of mistake.

Comment: I will be adding it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have **`has_many :comments`** in the **`Post`** model,your **`post_params`** method should be

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:post,:post_content,comments_attributes:[:comment])
end
```

Notice the the change i.e, **`comments_attributes`** not **`comment_attributes`**.